# CSV First line is always overridden (python)

Tags: python, csv, discord.py

I am programming a discord bot that lets users send an embed to a channel. The embed is split into multiple parts, which I want to safe to a CSV file because I want to add features that require the data to be saved. 
The problem is, that when a user executes the command, the first line in the CSV gets overridden with the new content of the command/embed. 
I tried to use a different mode to save to the next line. 'w' for writing is the one I am experiencing the problem with. The mode 'a' almost works, but it also adds the field names every time.

The CSV Code:

```py
with open('homework.csv', 'a', newline='') as file:
    fieldnames = ['user', 'fach', 'aufgabe', 'abgabedatum']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({'user': str(message.author), 'fach': subject, 'aufgabe': task, 'abgabedatum': date})
```

The CSV Output using the mode a

```
user,fach,aufgabe,abgabedatum
user,fach,aufgabe,abgabedatum
Akorian#0187,test,ja mddoiddn ,01.03.2021
user,fach,aufgabe,abgabedatum
Akorian#0187,testddd,ja mddoiddn ,01.03.2021
```

Comment: You should use the 'w+' mode instead of 'a' in your open call, otherwise it'll just keep overwritting on each write. At least, that's my guess without seeing your entire file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import csv
import os


if os.path.isfile('homework.csv'):
    with open('homework.csv', 'a', newline='') as file:
        fieldnames = ['user', 'fach', 'aufgabe', 'abgabedatum']
        w = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        w.writerow({'user': str(message.author), 'fach': subject, 'aufgabe': task, 'abgabedatum': date})
else:
    with open('homework.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
        fieldnames = ['user', 'fach', 'aufgabe', 'abgabedatum']
        w = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        w.writeheader()
        w.writerow({'user': str(message.author), 'fach': subject, 'aufgabe': task, 'abgabedatum': date})
```

Comment: Please explain the code, a simple "try this" message is not helpful, explain what's wrong with the questioner's code and what should he change.

Comment: It took me a while to understand your code. But I have to say, it is brilliant though an explanation would have been very helpful